# Terminology: Methods are ___ in a protocol (Objective C)

Tags: objective-c, ios, terminology

Just a quick question about terminology:  in the example below (pulled from Apple documentation), would we say these methods are "defined," "declared," or something else?

```
protocol XYZPieChartViewDataSource
- (NSUInteger)numberOfSegments;
- (CGFloat)sizeOfSegmentAtIndex:(NSUInteger)segmentIndex;
@optional
- (NSString *)titleForSegmentAtIndex:(NSUInteger)segmentIndex;    
@end
```

E.g., "You can see on line 2 that the numberOfSegments method is **__**.  Therefore, classes conforming to this protocol must implement this method."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> would we say these methods are "defined," "declared," or something else?

Declared.

Comment: OK, thanks for the reply.  And that whole example up there would be a protocol definition or declaration (or something else)?

Comment: By "introducing" the method signature to the compiler, you declare the method. Once you write the actual code of the method, you implement it. I'd just say you "write" the protocol, which declares the methods ...

Comment: @Rogare I'd say that's also a declaration - since you can't write actual code when composing a protocol, in my opinion a "protocol declaration" makes more sense than a "protocol definition".

Comment: @H2CO3 It's called a Protocol Definition by Apple. A declaration would be something like saying "There's a protocol called X but I'm not going to define what it means to adhere to it/what it contains," while when we define protocols we clearly define what it means to adhere to that specific protocol. Writing code has nothing to do with what the words mean when you think about it; they mean the same here as basically everywhere else. You *declare* something's existence, but *define* what it means. Unless I've royally messed something up. :p

Comment: Also, before someone thinks I'm saying something I'm not, the answer here is correct. The protocol has been defined but the methods have been declared like the answer says.

Comment: You're welcome. Also, +1. This could be useful to others having trouble discerning the difference between the two. I know for the first month learning C I couldn't remember what the difference was. xD